# AndroidStudio Excessive Number of Processes Running

Tags: android-studio

I'm having problems with AndroidStudio right now. Yesterday I worked on a project, and everything run correctly, right now the IDE it's stuck at running 4 processes. If you look on AndroidStudio on the status bars below, you'll see "Processes Running", right now I'm seeing 4 proceses runing and then AndroidStudio just freezes. Does someone knows why is this happening? If I comment the whole build.gradle from the App folder. it runs from 4 to 9-10 processes and then it blocks.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reasons, I disconnected my device and it worked. Don't know what really happened.